# How to use ON CONFLICT with Exclusion Constraint?

Tags: postgresql, upsert, exclusion-constraint

for example:
index by `userid`, `sdate`, `edate`

```
userid  sdate       edate
001     2019-01-01  2019-01-30
```

if I insert new data like:

```
userid  sdate       edate           
001     2019-01-03  2019-01-20  
   or
001     2019-01-13  2019-02-10  
   or
001     2019-02-01  2019-02-15
```

I tried below using GIST, but how to combine it using `ON CONFLICT`?

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist

CREATE TABLE test(
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
   USERID     CHAR(5),
   SDATE      DATE,
   EDATE      DATE,
   EXCLUDE USING gist
   (USERID WITH =,
   daterange(SDATE, EDATE, '[]') WITH &&)
);


Insert Into test (usersid, sdate, edate)
Values  (@UsersId, @SDate, @EDate) 
ON Conflict ON CONSTRAINT  test_userid_daterange_excl 
Do Update 
   Set sdate = @SDate, edate = @EDate
```

I got:

```
ERROR:  ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE not supported with exclusion constraints
```

based on the above scenario, I expect, the following:

```
userid  sdate       edate       I_EXPECT    
001     2019-01-03  2019-01-20  UPDATE because it is in range
001     2019-01-13  2019-02-10  UPDATE because it is in range
001     2019-02-01  2019-02-15  INSERT because it is not in range
```

select version() shows:

```
PostgreSQL 10.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit
```

Comment: I was going to suggest that you need a trigger to handle this, but maybe the Horse's suggestion would work too.

Comment: I got: 

        ERROR:  ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE not supported with exclusion constraints

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` with an exclusion index, like the error message says.

You will have to use code like in example 43.2 from [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-UPSERT-EXAMPLE).