# How to update with an exclusion index?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to insert records but where a match already exists, it should update but i keep getting the error below.

`ERROR:  ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE not supported with exclusion constraints`

Below is my update query

```
INSERT INTO table_b (b)
SELECT  array_remove(ARRAY[(SELECT id FROM table_c c WHERE c.id_a=u.id_a AND c.type_id=1),
(SELECT id FROM table_c c WHERE c.id_a=u.id_b AND c.type_id=2)],NULL)
FROM table_a u 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT b_constr 
DO UPDATE SET b =  EXCLUDED.b;
```

below is also a constraint on table_b

```
CREATE TABLE table_b
(
  id ,
  b integer[],
  CONSTRAINT b_constr EXCLUDE 
  USING gist (b WITH &&)
)
```

How do I get to update the rows where a match already exists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use ON CONFLICT with Exclusion Constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55919404/how-to-use-on-conflict-with-exclusion-constraint)

Comment: not really cause i need the update to be done. is there another way I can achieve that?